# Concatenate error output to error file set by System.setErr(...)

Tags: java

I want to print errors that happen in my app to a file. I do this by calling `System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("<path-to-file>")));`

However, whenever I restart my app the error file is rewritten. I want to concatenate new errors to the already existing file. Is there a way to do this?

NOTE: I don't want a logger. Already have that. The errors that will be in this file are of type `java.lang.Error` (such as OutOfMemoryError etc), not `java.lang.Exception`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `FileOutputStream` instead of `File` with `append` flag set to `true`:

`System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("<PathToFile>", true)));`